# jquery animation with click event

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

I want to bind a click event during a animate ,the following code are successful,but the `addscore()` funciton will do more then once,how to resolve it?

```
function moveObstacle(target,distance){
        target.removeClass('animated bounce');
        target.animate({ left: distance },{
            duration: 10000,
            progress: function(now, fx){
                $(this).addClass('animated bounce');
                $(this).click(function(){
                    $(this).hide();
                    addscore();
                });
            }
        }); 

    }


function addscore(){
        score2++;
        if(score2 == 10){
            score1++; score2 = 0;
        }
        $('.scoreNum').eq(0).html(score1);
        $('.scoreNum').eq(1).html(score2);
    }
```

Comment: Each time a progress callback is fired, you are binding a new click event, why that?!

Comment: I just want the thing that during a animate to click a image will add a score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is assign the click event handler outside the progress function and check for [:animated](https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)

It's not clear why you need 'animated bounce' class, so left this, but does not seem to be needed for the question  - you could use this to check if animating.

Also added complete: action to hide the target when the time is up.

```
function moveObstacle(target,distance){
    target.removeClass('animated bounce');
    target.click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":animated")) {
            $(this).hide();
            addscore();
        });
    });
    target.animate({ left: distance },{
        duration: 10000,
        progress: function(now, fx){
            $(this).addClass('animated bounce');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    }); 
}
```

An alternative is to assign the click when it starts and remove it when it stops:

```
function moveObstacle(target,distance){
    target.removeClass('animated bounce');
    target.click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        addscore();
    });
    target.animate({ left: distance },{
        duration: 10000,
        progress: function(now, fx){
            $(this).addClass('animated bounce');
        },
        complete: function() {
            target.off("click");
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it simpley by using bind() and unbind() methods. change your code as mentioned below.

```
$(this).unbind('click').bind('click'function(){
    $(this).hide();
    addscore();
});
```

Comment: I really don't get why OP would set it inside progress callback

Comment: Yes, Right, I also waiting for answer of your question asked on comment.. but any how this is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'off' and 'on' fonction to bind and unbind your event :

```
$(this).off('click').on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
    addscore();
});
```

The other way is to bind your event only when your animation start (suggested by [A.Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff))

```
 target.animate({
   left: distance
 }, {
   duration: 10000,
   start: function(fx) {
     $(this).click(function() {
       $(this).hide();
       addscore();
     });
   },
   progress: function(now, fx) {
     $(this).addClass('animated bounce');
   }
 });
```

Comment: This is just workaround regarding bad code logic. At least OP should use `start` not `progress`. And better would be to just delegate click event